# ASP.NET Request is not available in this context

Tags: asp.net

When I try to open the website, I get this problem and I have no idea whats wrong with it.
I have edited the stack trace with it

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    Request is not available in this context

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web  request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

    Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

    Source Error:

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace

    below.

Stack Trace:

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
       System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +8806688
       labs.shared.config.CFGConstants.InitializeFromHttpContext() +42
       labs.shared.config.CFGConstants..ctor() +722
       labs.shared.config.CFGConstants.Get() +108
       labs.site.framework.FWStateHelper.OnApplicationStart(HttpApplication app) +12
       labs.site.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +2724290
       System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +128
       System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +188
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +295
       System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetPipelineApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +56
       System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +231

    [HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8909915
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +333
```

Comment: Does this just happen all of a sudden?

Comment: Is there any inner exception?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are probably doing stuff in the `Application_Start` event handler. In IIS 7, **there is no `HttpRequest` available at that time**, and you shouldn't depend on a request for initializing your application.

If you really need request stuff early in your application's lifespan, you need to catch the first request getting through.

Comment: I was looking at the post 
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx
I believe it describes the same problem
Thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are mechanisms in place in IIS7 to force-run your application after a recycling, without a request being issued. Then the application will start, but a request might not arrive for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include the stack trace that you seem to have cut off. The description is pretty self evident that Request couldn't be used where you tried to use it. I suspect that you have tried to access the Request object in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler (that I think is called before things like Session and Request are initialised. I think that `Application_AcquireRequestState` is the earliest that Request is available...

Turns out from the stack trace you provided that the code is in `Application_Start` though the same as above applies. What are you trying to do here? Can it be done at a later stage? What is it actually getting from the Request object and can that information be obtained some other way?

You'll certainly need to move your code around somehow...