# How to redirect user while an error happens during OnApplicationStarted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a system version comparison during `OnApplicationStarted` method in Global.asax which does not allow the system boot up if the database version and system version are not matching.

So it looks like this:

```
protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
{
  try{
     if(systemVersion != dbVersion)
        throw new Exception("They are not same!");
  }
  catch{
    //do some other things
    //Response.Redirect("~/VersionError.html");
  }
}
```

but it says **"Response is not available in this context."** I tried to catch the error in `Application_Error` but I got the same error.

My question is that how I can redirect users to an error page from within these methods?

**Edit:**

I know there is no Response at this time **but I was asking how to get around this problem.** And also one of the reasons why I can hit methods after OnApplicationStarted is that we don't want to load many things if this exception occurs.

Comment: n IIS 7, there is no HttpRequest available at that time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791736/asp-net-request-is-not-available-in-this-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the Response when the application starts but want all incoming requests to go to an error page if a condition is met, you need to set up something farther up the pipeline.  Think IIS modules.  Install a module via the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="VersionsNotSameHandler" 
         type="Company.Exceptions.VersionsNotSameHandler, Company.Exceptions" 
         preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Now for the module code:

```
namespace Company.Exceptions
{
  public class VersionsNotSameHandler: IHttpModule
  {
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += newEventHandler(OnPreRequestHandlerExecute) 
    }

    public void OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object source, EventArgs e){

        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source; 
        HttpRequest request = app.Context.Request;
    // Check for invalid versioning
        app.Response.Redirect('.html page displaying error', true);
    }
  }
}
```

The OnPreRequest occurs before every request, making sure that the versions are always checked...you may want to cache if you notice things slowing down.

Answer (score 0):

There is no response at this point you are in application start!  This is when the application is starting not when a response is being made.

You could set something in here to direct every url to an error page if this condition is met by setting up a default route which will catch all requests.  This would kind of give you the functionality you want as future requests would then get an error page.

Comment: The thing I am trying to achieve is not to load anything before the condition is met so if I hit the Application_End page after the exception occurs, then it is too late as it loads a lot of things in Application Start.

Comment: So why cant you check for this condition if it is true then set a catch all route that will redirect to VersionError.html and if it is not true then run the rest of your setup code.  That way nothing else will run if that condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just throw an HTTP error:

```
throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
```

And then in your web.config:

```
  <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/VersionError.html"/>
  </customErrors>
```