# Request is not available in this context without Application_Start present

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I making changes to the old ASP.NET app created with Framework 2.0. 
Global.asax don't have Application_Start but when I'm debugging on IIS7 I'm getting error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request is not available in this context

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
System.Web.HttpContext.get_Request() +11207688
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.GetConfiguration(String 
configFilePath) +130
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.PopulateSection  
(ModulesConfigurationSection section, String rootDirectory) +274
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebConfigModuleInfoStore.GetModuleConfigurationSection
() +103
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.Services.WebModuleEnumerator.EnumerateModules() +216
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication.LoadModules() +443
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeWeb.WebClientApplication.Application_Start(Object sender,   
EventArgs e) +262

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext  
context, HttpApplication app) +4185553
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, 
HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +205
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr 
appContext, HttpContext context) +336
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext,
HttpContext context) +350
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +382

[HttpException (0x80004005): Request is not available in this context]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11335894
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +88
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr,
HttpContext context) +4355316
```

When I'm switching for development to the webserver part of VS I'm not getting any kind of error and everything working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Request is not available in this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791736/asp-net-request-is-not-available-in-this-context)

Comment: One more time Global.asax only contains Application_Error and nothing else

Comment: Alex, where you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @AlexKu, are you this guy... http://xkcd.com/979/ do you have the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the PnP guys overlooked this point in their designs: http://webclientguidance.codeplex.com/workitem/15451.

A possible workaround is available here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2008/03/11/wcsf-2-0-and-iis7-integrated-pipeline-mode.aspx